# Create nested list based on same key

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read csv file and combine values based on same key and there are multiple keys in a file.
I want to aggregate records based on the same key so that later I can access these records from list and pass it as values in the JSON request to API.

***csv file :***

```
claimId,subscriberId,claimType,claimSubType,providerId,totalChargeAmt,claimLineNo,pos_code,procedureCode,subdiagnosisCode,svcLineFromDt,svcLineToDt,chargedAmt,clmLineUnits,presentOnAdmit,diagnosisCode
18A000730400,101924200,M,M,002664514003,585,1,11,92014,H43393,2017-06-19,2017-06-19,160,1,U,H43393
18A000730400,101924200,M,M,002664514003,585,2,11,92014,H43393,2017-06-19,2017-06-19,160,2,U,H43394
```

***Code***

```
import csv
with open('JsonRequestPricingMedical.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

***Code output :***

```
['18A000730400', '101924200', 'M', 'M', '002664514003', '585', '1', '11', '92014', 'H43393', '2017-06-19', '2017-06-19', '160', '1', 'U', 'H43393']
['18A000730400', '101924200', 'M', 'M', '002664514003', '585', '2', '11', '92014', 'H43393', '2017-06-19', '2017-06-19', '160', '2', 'U', 'H43394']
```

***Desired output :***

There are two nested lists at the end.

```
['18A000730400', '101924200', 'M', 'M', '002664514003', '585', [['1', '11', '92014', 'H43393','2017-06-19', '2017-06-19', '160', '1'],['2', '11', '92014', 'H43393','2017-06-19', '2017-06-19', '160', '1']],[['U', 'H43393'],['U', 'H43394']]]
```

My goal is to achieve below layout.. I think once I have the data in the desired list format, I can take the values from list and pass it..

Json layout :

```
[
  {
   "claimsHeader":" {
    "claimId": "18A000730400",
    "subscriberId": "101924200",
    "claimType":{
                    "code": "M"
                },
     "claimSubType": {
                    "code": "M"
                },  
     "providerId" :"002664514003",
     "totalChargeAmt": "585",
     "claimLineDetail" :[
                {
                "claimLineNo": "1",
                 "placeOfService": {
                           "code": "11"
                },
                 "procedureCode": {
                        "code": "92014"
                },
                "subDiagnosisCd": {
                        "code": "H43393"
                },
                "svcLineFromDt": "2017-06-19",
                "svcLineToDt": "2017-06-19",
                "chargedAmt": "160",
                "clmLineUnits": "1",
                },
                {
                "claimLineNo": "2",
                 "placeOfService": {
                           "code": "12"
                },
                 "procedureCode": {
                        "code": "92015"
                },
                "subDiagnosisCd": {
                        "code": "H433945
                },
                "svcLineFromDt": "2017-06-19",
                "svcLineToDt": "2017-06-19",
                "chargedAmt": "160",
                "clmLineUnits": "2",
                }
     ],
     {
        "claimSpecDiag": [

            "presentOnAdmit": "",
            "diagnosisCode": "H43393",

         },
         {
            "presentOnAdmit": "",
            "diagnosisCode": "H43394",
         }

    ]   
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you explain the output? Why do you split at the differing key (1/2) first, but then on the same key (u/u)? Also, what do you intend to achieve with that? How do you know which of the first two lists belongs to which of the last two lists? And shouldn't the first part also be a nested list, just for consistency? And what if there are more than two lists, that may have much more complex "overlap"?

Comment: I have updated the json layout which I am trying to achieve.. I couldn't think of any other way except creating a list first then read values from there.. as we have nesting at the bottom in the json request.. I thought of creating it at the top only and pass it wherever it requires..

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are multiple entries (rows) with the same ID. If there are, read them into a list and start creating the result list:

```
[['18A000730400', '101924200', 'M', 'M', '002664514003', '585', '1', '11', '92014', 'H43393', '2017-06-19', '2017-06-19', '160', '1', 'U', 'H43393']
['18A000730400', '101924200', 'M', 'M', '002664514003', '585', '2', '11', '92014', 'H43393', '2017-06-19', '2017-06-19', '160', '2', 'U', 'H43394']]

# result list for now
['18A000730400', '101924200', 'M', 'M', '002664514003', '585']
```

Then, create a list from every entry for only those columns that you need in the list of lists. Because you know the indices of the elements in the original lists from csv, you can easily do that with list *slicing* `[a:b]`:

```
[['1', '11', '92014', 'H43393','2017-06-19', '2017-06-19', '160', '1'],['2', '11', '92014', 'H43393','2017-06-19', '2017-06-19', '160', '1']]

[['U', 'H43393'],['U', 'H43394']]
```

When you create that, just append it to the result list

It's a bit hard to explain this but I hope this gives you an idea. Feel free to ask me to clarify any part if you need :)